# Test first subnode from node

Tags: xslt, xpath

XML:

```
    <mode>
        <submode>1</submode>
        <submode>2</submode>
        <submode>3</submode>
        <submode>4</submode>
        <submode>5</submode>
        <submode>6</submode>
        <submode>7</submode>
    </mode>
    <mode>
        <submode>7</submode>
        <submode>8</submode>
        <submode>9</submode>
        <submode>10</submode>
        <submode>11</submode>
        <submode>12</submode>
        <submode>13</submode>
    </mode>
    <mode>
        <submode>14</submode>
        <submode>15</submode>
        <submode>16</submode>
        <submode>17</submode>
        <submode>18</submode>
        <submode>19</submode>
        20</submode>
    </mode>
```

How to test first `<submode>` from each `<mode>` (i need get numbers: **1, 7, 14**) in such construction:

```
<xsl:template match="submode">
    <xsl:if test="(parent::mode) and (...what?...)">
        ...
    </xsl:if>
    ...
</xsl:template>
```

I do not understand how use position() here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It is not generally true** that

`position() = 1`

evaluates to `true()` if the current node has a parent mode and the current node is the first `submode` child of its parent.

`position()` specifies the position of the current **node-list** and this is defined in a different way, depending on how the `select` attribute of `<xsl:apply-templates>` is specified.

For example (assuming that the provided XML has a top element that is the parent of the `mode` elements), if the template was selected when processingthe following:

`<xsl:apply-templates select="/*/mode/submode[. = 3]"/>`

then

`position() = 1`

is true only for the 3rd `submode` child of the first `mode` element.

**One correct answer:**

`parent::mode and not(preceding-sibling::submode)`

**Or, recommended**:

Have a separate template:

`<xsl:template match="mode/submode[1]">`

In this case no code within template is necessary to check if the current node is the first `submode` child -- this is already known to be so.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev, thank you very much, you, as always on top! Now i'll try to understand what you wrote, but the code certainly works (like any code from you). But if i "separate template" as you said i need to copy code for the execution from `<xsl:template match="submode">` to `<xsl:template match="mode/submode[1]">` - i do not want to do it.

Answer (score 1):

To count the number of `submode`s in the previous `mode` if and only if this is the first `submode` of the current `mode`, and avoid duplicating code between `<xsl:template match="submode">` and `<xsl:template match="submode[1]">`:

```
<!-- Special processing for first submode -->
<xsl:template match="submode[1]">
    <xsl:variable name="previousSubmodes" 
                  select="count(../preceding-sibling::mode/submode)"/>

    <!-- ... Do stuff with count ... -->

    <!-- Perform regular submode processing -->
    <xsl:call-template name="submode"/>

</xsl:template>

<!-- Regular processing for submodes -->
<xsl:template match="submode" name="submode">
    <!--  ... Do whatever ... -->
</xsl:template>
```

Alternatively, you can do the count processing from the template for `mode` instead.  That way, you will not need any special processing for the first `submode`.

```
<xsl:template match="mode">
    <!-- ... Other processing ... -->

    <xsl:variable name="previousSubmodes" 
                  select="count(preceding-sibling::mode/submode)"/>

    <!-- ... Do stuff with count ... -->

    <!-- Handle submodes; could use select="node()|@*" instead to process 
         everything, not just submodes  -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="submode"/>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="submode">
    <!--  ... Do whatever ... -->
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `<xsl:template match=` should read `"mode/submode[1]"`.

Then you'd have  the first `submode` of every `mode`.

Comment: @Jweede, I know, but I can not change the `<xsl:template match="submode">` because there is more code to do that is to be executed in any case, not only for the first node in `submode`.

Comment: Then you can add more templates, like what Dimitre recommends.